# sql error with php

Tags: php, html, sql

Hello everyone I have been having trouble with the following php code. 
It tells me that there was an error adding students.

Here is the code

[image]

Here is the error message

[image]

Please help im not sure why i am getting that error

Comment: Place the code as text so we can actually validate it. Also, even though I'm not sure how php works, can't you just let it throw a verbose error in order to understand what went wrong (like, not validating anything, just try and let it explode)?

Comment: 1. do not insert screenshots of code and errors, insert them **as text** in the question. and 2. even with a MINIMUM of error checking code you would get more info that "it failed". Add error checking code.

Comment: Try dumping out the mysql error (temporary while you fix this)

Comment: Oh no, sql injection, what is the compiled content of `$query`?

Comment: I'm not sure you pass strings with backticks, try single quotes instead

Comment: It looks like someone made my photos avaiable to see. The query variable is obviously failing but I do not know why. I looks up the syntax and everything is correct.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: How do I edit the question so i can post my code as text?

Comment: just under the tags (php, html) there's "edit" in grey

Answer (score -2):

I figured it out! 
My database was set to read only so it would not insert anything.

Thanks everybody